# Why is the placeholder font different and the submit button have additional text in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

The font of the placeholders for the inputs for a form are different in Firefox and I'm trying to figure out why that is and what could be causing that. Why does the submit button have some additional text as well in Firefox

This is how it's supposed to look (Chrome):

[image]

And this is how it looks on Firefox:

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="form appear appear-hidden" method="post">
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
    <div class="name-section">
      <input name="name" type="name" placeholder="Name" required />
      <input name="surname" type="surname" placeholder="Surname" required />
    </div>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />

    <textarea
      name = "message"
      type="message"
      placeholder="Message"
      row="4"
      required
    ></textarea>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" placeholder="submit" />
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 100px;
  color: white;
}

form h1 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.name-section input {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
}

form input {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

form input:-webkit-autofill,
form input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
form input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
form input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.submit {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  /* background-color: #000; */
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  resize: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.submit:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, keep in mind that Chrome (as well as Safari) uses WebKit. Firefox, however, uses Gecko. So everything with -webkit-[text] will not be applied in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

1. An `<input type="submit">` with no explicit value (read: "label") attribute will have a [default value chosen by the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#omitting_the_value_attribute). For Chrome, it is "Submit", Firefox is "Submit Query". To be consistent, explicitly set "value":

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

2. The placeholder color is coming through correctly, but Firefox sets placeholder opacity to [0.54 by default](https://reference.codeproject.com/css/::-moz-placeholder#:%7E:text=%5B1%5D%20Firefox%20applies%20a%20default,%2Dclass%20%3A%2Dmoz%2Dplaceholder%20.). To be consistent, explicitly set opacity:

```css
input::placeholder, textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `input::placeholder` and `textarea::placeholder`:

```
.input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #FFFFFF; opacity: 1;
}
.input:-moz-placeholder {
    color:#FFFFFF; opacity: 1;
}
```

As for the submit button having extra text, I can't really see any reason for that. Maybe try closing and reopening the firefox preview window?

Comment: As for the submit text: A `<input type="submit/>` will render as a button. And buttons do not support placeholder texts. And since you did not specify any other value, the browser will use a default text. For Firefox this is "Submit Query" and for Chrome it's just "Submit"